# How to break a long R markdown document

Tags: r, markdown, rstudio, knitr

I often find that in using RStudio R markdown, the resulting HTML can get quite long and heavy.  What strategies can someone use to break down or otherwise manage long documents?

Comment: What are you doing with the html that makes its size an issue? It must be very big to have a noticeable impact on download/viewing speeds. Or are you editing it by hand for some reason?

Comment: I'm not necessarily referring to the file size. More to the length of a document.

Comment: I don't understand the question. If the document is too long, this is because there's a lot of content in it. What kind of "strategies" are you referring to?

Comment: Thanks @Yihui  Can't wait!  Not even a hint...? ;-)

Comment: @CL: to make an analogy consider Kindle ebooks or other epub:  there's pagination, layout, frames to aid in readability, flow and clutter.  Think of Tufte's handout templates: lots of annotation and figures at margins. TOC as suggested below.  Those are what I call strategies to aid in readability, flow etc.

Comment: @ThomasSpeidel I can announce it now: https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/

Answer (score 2):

Create a table of contents (TOC) to move quickly to the different sections of your document. You do it by requesting a toc in the doc header, something like this:

```
---
title: "MyDoc"
output:
  html_document:
    toc: yes
---
```

Instead of being stuck at the top of a long document you can also produce a “floating toc" by adding a custom css-file. Have a look at this [example](http://rpubs.com/stevepowell99/floating-css).

Answer (score 1):

This is the default behavior of [**bookdown**](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown). See [Chapter 3](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/output-formats.html) of its documentation for details. In particular, look for the option `split_by` in 3.1.1 and 3.4.